# How to achieve desired block size with Hadoop with data on local filesystem

Tags: hadoop

I have a 2TB sequence file that I am trying to process with Hadoop which resides on a cluster set up to use a local (lustre) filesystem for storage instead of HDFS.  My problem is that no matter what I try, I am always forced to have about 66000 map tasks when I run a map/reduce jobs with this data as input.  This seems to correspond with a block size of 2TB/66000 =~ 32MB.  The actual computation in each map task executes very quickly, but the overhead associated with so many map tasks slows things down substantially.

For the job that created the data and for all subsequent jobs, I have dfs.block.size=536870912 and fs.local.block.size=536870912 (512MB).  I also found suggestions that said to try this:

```
hadoop fs -D fs.local.block.size=536870912 -put local_name remote_location
```

to make a new copy with larger blocks, which I did to no avail.  I have also changed the stripe size of the file on lustre.  It seems that any parameters having to do with block size are ignored for local file system.

I know that using lustre instead of HDFS is a non-traditional use of hadoop, but this is what I have to work with.  I'm wondering if others either have experience with this, or have any ideas to try other than what I have mentioned.

I am using cdh3u5 if that is useful.

Comment: Don't you think this is a problem with `Lustre` after all? I'm pretty sure they have a mailing list for these problems.

Comment: Yeah me too think it has something to do with `Lustre` itself.